# Android TabActivity: How to start only the activity from the currenttab?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

In my activity I have a `TabHost`.

I have 3 tabs and 3 activities for them. How can I start the corresponding activity when I click on a tab?

At the moment all three activities starts...

If I run this code, every activity (`connected_upload`, `connected_download`, `connected_search`)
runs the "`onCreate`" method.

How can I start those activities manually? I mean I like to start the  activity only when I click on the corresponding tab...

```
public class connected extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.connected);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables   
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost  
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab    
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab   

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, connected_upload.class);      
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Hoch").setIndicator("Hoch",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.freeftp)).setContent(intent); 
        tabHost.addTab(spec);   

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, connected_download.class); 
        String str_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        String str_profil = getIntent().getStringExtra("profil");
        String str_server = getIntent().getStringExtra("server");
        String str_port = getIntent().getStringExtra("port");
        String str_user = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
        String str_password = getIntent().getStringExtra("pw");

        intent.putExtra("path", str_path);
        intent.putExtra("profil", str_profil);
        intent.putExtra("server", str_server);
        intent.putExtra("port", str_port);
        intent.putExtra("user", str_user);
        intent.putExtra("pw", str_password);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Herunter").setIndicator("Herunter",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.freeftp)).setContent(intent); 
        tabHost.addTab(spec); 

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, connected_search.class); 
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Search").setIndicator("Search",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.freeftp)).setContent(intent); 
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

        //Button Connect Server
        Button cmd_mainsite = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but_connected_mainsite);
        cmd_mainsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){         
            public void onClick(View v){
                finish();
                Intent Intent_mainsite = new Intent(connected.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(Intent_mainsite); 
            }       
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This Code As per your requirement

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {


                        @Override
                        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                            setContentView(R.layout.main);

                           Resources res = getResources();
                            TabHost th = getTabHost();

                            th.addTab(th.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("tab1",
                                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).
                                    setContent(new Intent(this, firsttab.class)));
                            th.addTab(th.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("tab2")
                                    .setContent(new Intent(this, secondtab.class)));
                            th.addTab(th.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("tab3")
                                    .setContent(new Intent(this, thirdtab.class)));

    th.setCurrentTab(1);
                }
                }
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                 android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                 android:layout_weight="1">

                </FrameLayout>
                 <TabWidget 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@android:id/tabs">
                </TabWidget>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
```

**firsttab.java**

```
public class firsttab extends Activity {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("HI");
            tv.setTextSize(25);
            setContentView(tv);
        }

    }
```

**secondtab.java**

```
public class secondtab extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello");
        tv.setTextSize(25);
        setContentView(tv);
    }

}
```

**thirdtab.java**

```
public class thirdtab extends Activity {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("How Are U?");
            tv.setTextSize(25);
            setContentView(tv);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'll try it soon. Thanks and happy X-Mas :)

Answer (score 0):

Write below code for open activity on click of particular tab and if you have any query regarding that then tell me.

TabActivity.java:-

```
public class TabActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_screen);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityStack.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId").setIndicator("Temp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
        spec.setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityStack.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId").setIndicator("Temp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.invoice));
        spec1.setContent(intent1);

        tabHost.addTab(spec1);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an onCreate method in my mainactivity. Take a look to my edit code in the question.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class connected extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.connected);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables   
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost  
TabSpec spec1= tabHost.newTabSpec("")
                .setIndicator("Hoch",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.freeftp))
                .setContent(new Intent(this, connected_upload.class));
        tabHost.addTab(spec1);

        TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("")
                .setIndicator("Herunter",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.freeftp))
                .setContent(new Intent(this, connected_download.class));



        String str_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        String str_profil = getIntent().getStringExtra("profil");
        String str_server = getIntent().getStringExtra("server");
        String str_port = getIntent().getStringExtra("port");
        String str_user = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
        String str_password = getIntent().getStringExtra("pw");

        intent.putExtra("path", str_path);
        intent.putExtra("profil", str_profil);
        intent.putExtra("server", str_server);
        intent.putExtra("port", str_port);
        intent.putExtra("user", str_user);
        intent.putExtra("pw", str_password);

        tabHost.addTab(spec2);

    TabSpec spec3= tabHost.newTabSpec("")
                .setIndicator("Search",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.freeftp))
                .setContent(new Intent(this, connected_search.class));
        tabHost.addTab(spec3);

      tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

        //Button Connect Server
        Button cmd_mainsite = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but_connected_mainsite);
        cmd_mainsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){         
            public void onClick(View v){
                finish();
                Intent Intent_mainsite = new Intent(connected.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(Intent_mainsite); 
            }       
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: by default first your selected tab is opened. when u click on remaining two tabs corresponding activity will come. code is working. wat's ur requirement?

Comment: no, when I start my app the onCreate method from all three activities will start.

Comment: u want to start all 3 activities at a time or when u click on pariculat tab, it open. In my code first by default second actvity will open , then when u click on remaining activities, corresponding activity open.

Comment: I want to start the activity when I click on the tab AND NOT all three at the same time. When I try it with your code, connected_upload starts and then connected_download starts and then connected_search. So its not seperatly